# Can this select/map be made more readable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have an array of objects from ActiveRecord that I'm running `select` and `map` on to get some values:

```
@jobs.select{|u| u[:user_id] == user.id}.map{|t| t[:regular_time]}.sum
```

Is there are more readable way to do this?

There will be quite a few variations of this with the `map` variable changed, like this:

```
@jobs.select{|u| u[:user_id] == user.id}.map{|t| t[:ot_time]}.sum
@jobs.select{|u| u[:user_id] == user.id}.map{|t| t[:vacation_time]}.sum
@jobs.select{|u| u[:user_id] == user.id}.map{|t| t[:holiday]}.sum
```

The reason for doing it this way is I've already got the data loaded in a single query, from which I then split it out into users and then various bits of data associated with each user.

Really just done this way to avoid making thousands of DB calls.

Comment: How about creating a method?

Comment: why not `@jobs.select{|u| u.user_id == user.id}.map(&:regular_time).sum`

Comment: Is it possible to at least limit the jobs by user in your database query instead? Then you wouldn't even need to do the first select.

Comment: This definitely seems like it would be better handled in the database query - doing this in ruby code will be a lot slower because all of the objects need to be loaded into memory.

Comment: @DaveMongoose So better to make hundreds, if not thousands, of additional queries?

Comment: I don't know what your use case is so I can't really judge, but if it's lots of sums and assuming it's a SQL-based database, you can use `SELECT SUM(ot_time), SUM(vacation_time), SUM(holiday),...` with `GROUP BY user_id` to do it all in one query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is fine. If you want you could still split it using a lambda:

```
right_user = -> u {u[:user_id] == user.id } #creating a lambda
@jobs.select(&right_user).map(&:regular_time).sum
```

Note that

```
right_user = -> u {u[:user_id] == user.id } #creating a lambda
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
right_user = lambda { |u| u[:user_id] == user.id } #creating a lambda
```

Answer (score 2):

I would group the jobs by `user_id` using [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
@jobs_by_user = @jobs.group_by(&:user_id)
```

and calculate the sums with:

```
@jobs_by_user[user.id].sum(&:ot_time)
@jobs_by_user[user.id].sum(&:vacation_time)
@jobs_by_user[user.id].sum(&:holiday)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a User has many Jobs.  If thats the case then you can use active record

```
user.jobs.sum(:regular_time)
user.jobs.sum(:ot_time)
....
```

If you don't want to use active record (avoid db queries if your items are already loaded), then all you can do is whats been mentioned in the comments already.  I'm a fan of using `.map(&:attribute_name).sum`